# What specific error am I getting when I make a request to a server that is completely offline?

Tags: web-services, http

I looked online but I could not get a clear answer.

Would I get a 503 Service Unavailable, because the DNS is still running but the web server is down? Or something else.

Comment: A timeout, because there's nothing to connect to.

Comment: so would that be a 408 timeout? Or will the socket itself time out

Comment: that doesn't make sense because a 408 timeout, the socket does timeout, but what I mean is

Comment: is it a 408 or a different timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiving a 408 error, or any HTTP error for that matter, would require a valid connection to the server. Since in your example the server is offline, the request would time out and a socket would never be created.

Comment: do all http status codes imply some sort of connection to the server?

Comment: Yes. HTTP status codes are response codes.  Without a connection, there is no response.